# form submit phonegap jqtouch

Tags: php, forms, cordova, submit, jqtouch

i have seen similar posts here but i have had no luck solving my problem so I thought I'd ask:

i am using jqtouch framework to submit a form (index.html) to a php file on my webserver (myphpfile.php)...

in my index.html:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="http://mydomain.com/myphpfile.php">
//form inputs
<input type="hidden" id="doSubmit" name="doSubmit" value="Submit">
<a href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Submit!</a>
</form>
```

this works in web browsers (firefox, safari, chrome), see www.newhereinc.com but when it is compiled in xcode with phone gap it doesn't submit the form

I have also added "*" and "*.*" to Phonegap plist file ExternalHosts Array...with no luck

I have read that I need to do this as a XHR Post request...which i am unfamiliar with?

any help would e greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form class="myformid" method="post" >

//form inputs
<input type="hidden" id="doSubmit" name="doSubmit" value="Submit">

<a href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Submit!</a>
</form>




$('#myformid').submit(function() {

var formdata = $("#myformid").serialize();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: http://mydomain.com/myphpfile.php,
  data: formdata,
  success: success,
  dataType: json,
});
})
```